# ImageMagick command-line gradient

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using an example for ImageMagick's gradient found here:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#tilt_shift

The arguments are as follows:

```
magick convert beijing_contrast.jpg -sparse-color Barycentric "0,0 black 0,%h white"-function polynomial 4,-4,1 beijing_blurmap.jpg
```

It creates a perfect gradient image with white at the top and bottom:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to do the same thing for portrait image (make white at the left and right edges).

Please help.

Comment: You could rotate the image from landscape to portrate after creating it or before using it. If you are using Imagemagick version 7 you should only need magick without the convert. magick convert uses a v6 legacy version.

Comment: @Bonzo rotation isn't ideal as it adds unnecessary extra processing. I guess the right thing is to figure out the new polynomial arguments to do the same thing horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagmagick, just change the arguments to sparse-color. Use %w,0 rather than 0,%h. Note also that in Imagemagick 7, you should use just magick and not magick convert and not convert. Otherwise, you may get IM 6 behavior. For other tools such as identify and mogrify and montage, etc, you do need to preface those with magick. Note also you are missing a space before -function. Try

```
magick beijing_contrast.jpg -sparse-color Barycentric "0,0 black %w,0 white" -function polynomial 4,-4,1 beijing_blurmap.jpg
```

If needed, swap the black and white depending upon whether you want it white in the middle or black in the middle.

For IM 6.9.2.5 or higher, there are new convenience defines for creating various directional gradient. But you need to specify the image size. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/gradient.php